# Get Now Date and Time

Tags: java, datetime, jpa

I'm using JPA and I want to store the date in this format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

So I create a function

```
public static String getNowDate() {
    Date date = new Date();
    final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

The problem is that this returns a String and I need a date.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date creationDate;
```

How do I make this work so I can save date and time exactly like that?

I know a easy solution is to declare creationDate as String. Is this too bad?

Comment: the problem is that the constructor expects date and this function returns String

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated (along with `Date`), it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Also, as the answer says, store a date-time object like `Instant` or `LocalDateTime` to your database, not a string.

Comment: Date-time columns in a database do not have a “format”.

Answer (score 6):

There is a problem with the premise to your question.  Ideally, your current timestamp will be stored in a SQL database, in some sort of date column, and not as text.  Since you are using JPA, backed by JDBC, you should just be inserting a date type.  So, something like the following should work:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
// or maybe just
Date now = new Date();
```

Then, just let JPA worry about how to martial the current timestamp into your database table.  If you really need to *format* your timestamp as shown, then worry about this in your Java code somewhere.

Comment: I can't use that. I dont have the import. Only appears .sql and .security Do I need a maven dependency?

Comment: @user9800607 Then just use a regular Java `Date`.  The crux of my answer is that the internal format a SQL date is generally out of scope most of the time.  Let the database worry about how to store a date/timestamp.  You only need to know how to _instruct_ JPA to persist the timestamp you want.

Comment: I see I need .sql. But are you telling me I need to convert this in my frontend ( javascript) `2018-05-16T14:09:08.361+0000` how??

Comment: Frontend?  Where did that come from?  I thought you were asking about JPA and databases?